# Create Trigger - SQL Error [1064] [42000]

Tags: sql, triggers, mariadb, syntax-error

I want to create a trigger.

```
create trigger bi_validate_users
before insert on users
for each row 
begin
    if new.user = '' then 
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'User must not be blank';
    end if;
    if new.password = '' then 
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = 'Password must not be blank';
    end if;
end
```

I get this error message:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: (conn=26) You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Try a delimiter $$ at the beginning

Comment: I added DELIMITER $$ to the first line. The error message is gone, but the trigger is still not created.

Comment: i can not reproduce your error this doesn't need DELIMITER  https://dbfiddle.uk/f-UAfqiM   copy the code from the fiddle and try it again

Comment: Tried, but does not work. Maybe it will be easier for you to understand if you watch the video shortly where I got the code. Starts from 02:41.  https://youtu.be/KfS8I6DizNM?t=161

Comment: are you using dbbeaver too?  and which version of mariadb have you running

Comment: Yes, I use DBeaver 23.1.2 and MariaDB 11.2.0.

Comment: your version is still in beta phase,so can have still bugs, use the regular 11.0 o even a prior version